# Routing and SEFURL with .htaccess on an independent project

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've developed a small (and powerful and lightweight :-D) php MVC Framework

the issue I'm currently having is: 
the routes follow this order

index.php?option=samplemodule&action=sampleController

That would link to a samplemodule and would execute the sampleController, pretty much as zf used to do a while ago.

I'm trying to get the .htaccess to rewrite the rules as
/module/action

but for some reason it's not working, here's the piece of the code

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule     ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?option=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?option=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?option=$1&action=main [NC,L]
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?option=$1&action=main [NC,L]
```

Dealing with regexes is quite difficult

i'd also like it to, when passing variables, these could be in the form of 
/module/action/var1/value1/var2/value2

but i'm not sure of how the rewrite pattern engine works.... does it use several rules recursively?

Answer (score 1):

> does it use several rules recursively?

It does, but it's not as simple as it sounds.

As far as URL patterns that can go on indefinitely like: /module/action/var1/value1/var2/value2

you can try something like this:

```
# turn everything after /module/action/XXXX to query string variables
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ /$1/$2/$5?$3=$4 [L,QSA]

# turn /module/action/ into option= and action=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?option=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]

# turn /module/ into option= and action=main
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?option=$1&action=main [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it's not working lol. So if you put the L quote at the end, it will take that as the last rule and it won't keep analyzing. the problem is... how do I do it so it keeps rewriting? . so lets say i have the following string

var1/a/var2/b/var3/c/var4/d/var5/d/var6/f

the program will match the first var1/a/var2/a and then leave the rest /var3/c/var4/d.... for the other two rules that dont match :S